# Set location.search query string without re-render with react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Background:

- Page is rendered with a search criteria form, and search results
- After the search button is pressed, the search is performed and results are displayed
- When results are received from the API request, we want to store the search criteria on the URL in the query params. This allows that same search to be sharable with others with just the URL

We have attempted to accomplish the last point by updating `location.search` directly, as well as using React Router's `history` prop. It successfully updates the URL, but React Router detects the URL change, and processes it again, resulting in the entire flow going into an infinite loop.

Is there a way to set the query parameters without React Router processing the change?

Comment: Please provide a relevant code that creates this problem

Comment: You can use `shouldComponentUpdate` to cancel any updates on history changes. Other than that, I'm not sure because you are directly manipulating the browser history and react-router is already subscribed to any changes, so I don't think you can prevent it from seeing the changes.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem yet?